# django model validation not working

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following model:

```
class CardInfo(models.Model):
    custid = models.CharField(max_length=30, db_index=True, primary_key = True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    street = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    building = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    payment_method = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    amount = models.CharField(default = '0',max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
    valid_to_month = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    valid_to_year = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
def __unicode__(self):
    return "Cust ID %s" %(self.custid)
```

In the shell, when i give full_clean i get validation error but on save it s getting saved rather than throwing error. why is this so? i am using django1.3 and python 2.6:

```
c=CardInfo(custid="Asasasas")
c.full_clean()
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/local/python2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 828, in full_clean
raise ValidationError(errors)
ValidationError: {'building': [u'This field cannot be blank.'], 'city': [u'This field cannot be blank.'], 'first_name': [u'This field cannot be blank.'], 'last_name': [u'This field cannot be blank.'], 'zipcode': [u'This field cannot be blank.'], 'state': [u'This field cannot be blank.'], 'street': [u'This field cannot be blank.']}
c.save()
```

Comment: It should give integrity error. Is your models/db synced properly? sqlall of your app will be helpful.

Comment: yeah i have done that...no improvement

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The documentation is [explicit about this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/validators/#how-validators-are-run):

> Note that validators will not be run automatically when you save a model, but if you are using a ModelForm, it will run your validators on any fields that are included in your form.

It's your responsibility to call the clean methods before saving if you're not using a form.

Calling the model validators can be forced like this:

```
model_instance.full_clean()
```